# Very strange error in code?

Tags: android, android-studio

Very strange error in code. The part right after the semicolon in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is underlined in red. everytime I try to put up code block there. I am pretty sure my brackets add up correctly and there is no syntax error in the xml as well. Then Why is the red underlined ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


public void function_name(View view){
    /* code for the actual program including some declarations. */


}
```

I don't get it can someone help ?

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket for the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @MikeM.No it is there in the code. It was a copy paste mistake form my code. I am editing the question now

Comment: Where is close bracket for `onCreate()` method

Comment: You need a closing bracket for your `onCreate()` method before declaring another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not added `}` in `onCreate` method. You should define methods outside of `onCreate` method.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void function_name(View view){
    /* code for the actual program including some declarations. */


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `}` in `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```